# Enabling/Disabling specific OSGi bundles of clusters in Netbeans Platform Application

Tags: osgi, netbeans-platform

We are developing a Netbeans RCP application that includes NB modules, and OSGi modules. Focus of the problem is within the OSGi bundles. So I will explain about the details with the OSGi bundles.

In this RCP application, OSGi bundles are formed as Netbeans clusters. And these clusters are included in Netbeans Platform application. Everything is okay until now. We can run OSGi bundles in Netbeans platform app with success.

But, when we try to untick a specific OSGi bundle in included cluster( in Netbeans Platform App project ), Netbeans platform application does not simply turns off the OSGi module. It still continues to load it with application.

When the same action is done with a Netbeans module(not an OSGi module), this problem does not occur, simply module is disabled and unloaded.

Netbeans version is 7.3.1, we have tried cleaning cache, suite build etc.. But no success. I have to mention also that OSGi declarative services are used( one of the possible suspects also )

Is there any way to specialize which OSGi modules in a cluster will be included in main Netbeans Platform Application ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bug to me. You should report it [here](https://netbeans.org/community/issues.html), a small test case should speed up the bug report.

Comment: Are you sure ? Marking this as a bug, may avoid further answers or solutions?

Comment: Sure about what?
   a) Sure about it's a bug? No, I'm not sure, that's why I said "I think". 
   b) Sure about reporting it? Yea, I'm sure it's a good idea to report it. 

I don't know if marking it as a bug will avoid further answers/solutions @ stack overflow, but I think it will allow further answers/solutions @ netbeans, where NetBeans experts will offer better solutions.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer.. But the source of the answer is important. I can öpen the bug directly to nb tracker. But i want to verify that it is not our fault.

Comment: Bug confirmed and taken for resolution. Thanks for the help

Comment: Good to know. Thank you for reporting it, as this makes NetBeans better!